# What edition of Salesforce must I have to use the API?

Tags: api, editions

I'm looking at the editions and pricing page at Salesforce.com http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing.jsp and only the Enterprise option says "Integration via web service API". I'm wondering if that means I won't have access to the REST and SOAP APIs in other versions.

Can you use the API in all versions or just Enterprise and up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API are enable only for Enterprise and above editions by default + free developer account.

You can pay extra and enable API feature for professional edition.

Comment: You *may* be able to get API in Professional Edition. Sometimes they let you, sometimes they don't. The policy keeps changing from time to time.